# Tabulator Table Constantly Expanding Width on Row Select

Tags: tabular, bulma

Using Tabulator 4.9.1 + Bulma CSS 0.9.1

I have a simple table

If that table is loaded on the page, when i select a row, it works fine

However, when I have same table in a Modal, and I selected a row, the table begins to expanding horizontally on the right, does not stop until i deSelect the row (does not return to original size); in maintains that width and if i select it again (any row) it expands from that point on

Answer (score 0):

Found out one of my classes above  (3 parents above) had a display: flex
That caused the table to keep expanding\growing once a row is selected (and maintain selected).  Once you unselect it, the expanding/growing stops

Comment: The culprit is the checkbox column for row select

    {
      formatter: "rowSelection",
      hozAlign: "center",
      headerSort: false,
      cellClick: (e, cell) => {
        cell.getRow().toggleSelect();
      }
    },